# Cannot enable checkboxes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET website.  A checkbox is created in the code behind and disabled as follows:

```
cBox = New CheckBox
cBox.ID = "Link" & lngUSN & "|" & objTableMapping.DatasetName & "|" & CStr(objDRInput("URNs")) & "|" & intLinkCount & "|" & objTableMapping.Reference
cBox.InputAttributes.Add("class", "Link" & lngUSN & "|" & objTableMapping.DatasetName & "|" & CStr(objDRInput("URNs"))) '& "|" & intLinkCount)
cBox.Checked = False
cBox.Enabled = False
```

After the page has loaded (loaded through AJAX), the checkboxes should be enabled as follows:

```
window.onload = EnableLinkAndUnLinkCheckboxes;

function EnableLinkAndUnLinkCheckboxes()
    {
        //Go through all of the checkboxes on the webpage and ensure they are enabled
        var frm = document.forms[0];
        for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
            if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
                alert('got here')
                frm.elements[i].disabled = false;
                }
            }
    }
```

The 'Got here' alert appears many times meaning the following code is reached: `frm.elements[i].disabled = false;`, however the checkboxes are not enabled.  Why is this?

Comment: Did you try to remove attribute displayed with `removeAttribute`?

Comment: forgot a semicolon after `alert('got here')`

Comment: are you sure `elements` are the correct ones? Cause this works http://jsfiddle.net/dL8xr0bp/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below one.

```
function EnableLinkAndUnLinkCheckboxes() {
        //Go through all of the checkboxes on the webpage and ensure they are enabled
        var frm = document.forms[0];
        for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
            if (frm.elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
                frm.elements[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
                frm.elements[i].parentElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  That does seem to work, but what is the point of this line: frm.elements[i].parentElement.removeAttribute('disabled');?

Comment: for check box, browser rendering '<span>' as parent element for the '<input>' type of check box. And it has attribute 'disabled' whenever we disable the check box. so we need to remove this attribute also in case if we want to enable through script.

moreover i see this parent element problem in IE alone, FF is working fine up on skipping that line.

Please mark this as answer if it helps to you.